# iPhone Web Service

Tags: php, ios, iphone, web-services

I am working on a project where I have to send the details of the users to the server to register in the app. I am done with the UI but not able to find solution to how I can send the users details such as Name, Phone number, address and all. I would need someone to guide me through the process from the beginning. The back end is already written and it is in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works 100%

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",@"Raja",@"12345"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/promos/index.php"]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if( theConnection ){
    // indicator.hidden = NO;
    mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
```

your PHP code

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];


    echo $username;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have backend written already, you can send data to server and get back via `NSURLSession` in iOS 7. Below example will send send username and password to server in JSON format.

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL to which you want to send data"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *data =@{"userName":"Abc","password","xyz"}
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
// write logic after geting response from the server 
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```