# AFNetworking post not working?

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking

I have some problems with my post, once i press my "send" button i receive an e-mail, but it does not contain the inputs which i made in the text fields. 
i just get an empty e-mail.

**here is my viewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"    
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize firstname,lastname,text;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

-(IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[firstname]":firstname ,

                             @"user[lastname]": lastname,

                             @"user[text]":text};

    manager.responseSerializer= [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:@"http://www.mytestpage.com/test/mail.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
  }

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.firstname resignFirstResponder];
    [self.lastname resignFirstResponder];
    [self.text resignFirstResponder];

}


@end
```

Comment: first search google on about your question because plenty of answer available in SOF(stackoverflow)

Comment: thats what i did before i asked. but i cant find the problem why it does not work with this code.

Comment: what happen in your json reponse

Comment: i receive an email- but it contains nothing, dont know if there are problems with my params

Comment: may be it return wrong json from your server did check that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675234/iphone-web-service/21675603#21675603

Comment: just take this php example and work with AFNetworking method. if it works. your server have return messed up something

Comment: i tried to use the code you gave me in the link above and get this failure: Unknown Type of name "mutableData"

if( theConnection ){

    // indicator.hidden = NO;

    mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

Comment: you should initialize  nsmutable data in your .h or .m file

Comment: may the problem be, that my button does not get the content of the text fields to send them?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with this one

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mytestpage.com/test/mail.php"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSString *usrpwdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[firstname]=%@&user[lastname]=%@&user[text]=%@", firstname, lastname, text];
    [request setHTTPBody:[usrpwdStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON];
        NSLog(@"dictionary =%@",dict);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"error =%@",error);
    }];
    [operation start];
```

Thanks